# How to test the difference between two differences in coefficient?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, regression-coefficients, differences

I am running this regression: Y= X1 + X2 + controls. I would like to see if the relation between Y and X1 is different at different levels of X2. So I slip by sample into two groups by X2: high and low, and then run Y=X1+controls for each group. I know I can use SUEST in Stata to test the difference between the two coefficients on X1.

However, I also have two time periods: time1 and time2. I would like to see if the difference between the two coefficients in time1 is significantly different from time2. How to compute the test statistics? is there a way to do it in Stata?..

I know I can run a regression with a three-way interaction like this: 
Y = X1 + X2 + time + X1 * X2 * time + controls;
But I want to avoid running something like this for its many problems (multicollinearity, etc).

Thanks!